# how to get magento collection by created at on list.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I tried to get new product ...bt this was not coming if ...i didn't place product new from date in magento..

I code something for getting new product in magento...bt its not coming on base of created at..

i need to know that what should i change in my code for new product...

I need to show new product on list.phtml in magento product listing page

my code is bellow.

```
 $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                )
          )
        ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Rewrite Block associated with .phtml you want to overwrite.

Step 2 : add block related xml and associate a .phtml to this block.

Step 3 : Now create this .phtml file and use your new block call to fill dynamic part of that .phtml file part.